# how can i make a SL & TP with 1.5:1 RR ratio

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Hi I started with pine script yesterday and I can't figure out how I can make my take profit 1.5x bigger than my stop loss. My stop loss is set to the 50EMA and I want my take profit to be 1.5x bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need or the actual code you need

Tp = entry price + ((entry price - SL price) * 1.5)